# Joomla .htaccess - images gone

Tags: image, .htaccess, joomla, file-permissions

I opened a folder (/images/Icons) inside the joomla installation image folder with a .htaccess file with this content

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Then I moved that folder to root and deleted the .htaccess from it. Now the Joomla CMS is not recognizing the images anymore, but recognizes the image folder as "writable".

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the only thing you did was deleting that specific folder? Can you provide the relative path to this folder? (e.g. /images/deleted_folder)

Comment: it was images/Icons and inside was an Icon for google maps, which is why I did the .htaccess in the first place.

Then I moved the Icons folder to root and deleted the .htaccess from it because the images were not showing up and it was the only thing I had changed. but it stayed broken.

Comment: Ok, and all images aren't showing up, or only the images in your Icons folder? And before you moved the folder, did the image(es) in your Icons folder show up?

I noticed that your folder-name starts with a capital letter i, does the path to you image contain this capital i as well?

Comment: all images, in the /images folder, which has ca. 10 subfolders. the problem is not about the image in the Icons folder, but about the images used by joomla.

Inside the backend, I can see the files but they all display a broken image. and in the frontend, they just display the alt text.